# Realtme notification using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, websocket

How create notification realtime using framework codeigniter in localhost step by step, with node.js, or websocket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: `http://pusher.com/`

One more apparent solution for realtime updates is 'Reverse Ajax'

If you are interested running this internally without using a service such as pusher have a look at `http://www.ape-project.org/` for setting up your own push server (based on Comet Server)

I wont say much more as the links above explains it far more elegantly!